# Does Ubuntu 16.04 server supports kernel version 5.4?

Tags: 16.04, server, kernel, linux-headers

Is there any recommended kernel version to use for ubuntu 16.04 server? Does it supports latest kernel version 5.4? will it cause any issue?

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 will go EOL at the end of April 2021 - in 3 days time and thus be outside the support cycle.

Comment: https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/

Comment: I pretty much always run the most recent development kernels. A couple of years ago it became a problem with the most recent kernel on a Ubuntu16.04 server, and I was forced to update my test server to 18.04 (at the time). I forget the details.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 16.04 offers two software stacks

- the GA (general) kernel stack is 4.4, which is the original kernel it released with and is supported the entire life of the product, or
- the HWE stack, which progressed through it's life (*using 16.10, 17.04, 17.10 before finally settling on 18.04's GA kernel*) of 4.15

Those are the two fully supported kernel stacks of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

If you need a later kernel though, given Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is in it's *final days of support* (without switching to 16.04 ESM), I'd suggest upgrade.  I'd also suggest upgrade, or at least researching ESM if you need to remain on 16.04 and can use one of the supported stacks.

Notice of this can be found at [Extended Security Maintenance for Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus begins April 30, 2021](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/)

For details on HWE please see

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack

Comment: My host system is ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and kernel version is 5.4.0-72-generic. I'll be running lxc containers with ubuntu 16.04 in this host (using this version due to the expected software version is not available in higher ubuntu os but soon we'll upgrade). So here the kernel will be the same for containers right? In this case, will this cause any issue for container?

Comment: Is fully virtualized, instead of lxc containers, an option? I am running a 16.04 Ubuntu server VM guest with kernel 4.4.0-209-generic on a Ubuntu 20.04 server host running 5.4.0-72-generic right now.